# How to return different value in Mockito based on parameter attribute?

Tags: java, mockito

The class that I test receive a client wrapper:

The tested class (snippest)

```
private ClientWrapper cw
public Tested(ClientWrapper cw) {
    this.cw = cw;
}

public String get(Request request) {
    return cw.getClient().get(request);
}
```

The test initialization:

```
ClientWrapper cw = Mockito.mock(ClientWrapper.class);
Client client = Mockito.mock(Client.class);
Mockito.when(cw.getClient()).thenReturn(client);
//Here is where I want to alternate the return value:
Mockito.when(client.get(Mockito.any(Request.class))).thenReturn("100");
```

In the exmaple I always return "100", but the Request have an attribute `id` and I would like to return different values to `client.get(Request)` based on the `request.getId()` value.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use Mockito's answers, so instead of:

```
Mockito.when(client.get(Mockito.any(Request.class))).thenReturn("100");
```

write:

```
Mockito.when(client.get(Mockito.any(Request.class)))
 .thenAnswer(new Answer() {
   Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
     Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
     Object mock = invocation.getMock();
     return "called with arguments: " + args;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You could create an `ArgumentMatcher` to let you match the `Request` by id.

So the argument matcher would be like this:

import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher;

```
public class IsRequestWithId implements ArgumentMatcher<Request> {
    private final int id;

    public IsRequestWithId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object arg) {
        Request request = (Request)arg;
        return id == request.getId();
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
Mockito.when(client.get(Mockito.argThat(new IsRequestWithId(1)))).thenReturn("100");
Mockito.when(client.get(Mockito.argThat(new IsRequestWithId(2)))).thenReturn("200");
```

Otherwise using an `Answer` would also work, but using an `ArgumentMatcher` lets you keep the code more "declarative".

Comment: Which "Request" class, I can't seem to find the proper class that has the ".getId()" getter. Thanks

Comment: `Request` is the class you are trying to test/mock.

Answer (score 9):

In order to do it right and with minimal code you have to use the `ArgumentMatcher`, lambda expression & **don't forget** to do a null check on the filters members in the `ArgumentMatcher` lambda (especially if you have more than one mock with the same `ArgumentMatcher`).

Customized argument matcher:

```
private ArgumentMatcher<Request> matchRequestId(final String target) {
    return request -> request != null &&
            target.equals(request.getId());
}
```

Usage:

```
 given(client.get(argThat(matchRequestId("1")))).willReturn("100");
 given(client.get(argThat(matchRequestId("2")))).willReturn("200");
```